# Bootstrap 3 Collapsing Menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just recently downloaded the latest version of bootstrap...
I built a collapsing nav and it does what it is intended but,
when you roll over the menu icon after it collapses nothing 
happens. In all the demos the nav pops down. Ive downloaded 
examples and they dont work after the menu is hidden either¿
Ive looked all over for a solution?Any assistance would be 
greatly appreciated! Im including the code written..

**CSS**

```css
/*nav styles*/
.navbar{
    background:none;
}
.nav{
    margin-top:77px;
    margin-right:5%;
}

.navbar .brand {
    max-height: 40px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar .nav  li{
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar .nav  li a{
    background-color: #00AFE7;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-transition:background 1s ease;
-moz-transition:background 1s ease;
-o-transition:background 1s ease;
transition:background 1s ease;
}

.navbar .nav li  a:focus,
.navbar .nav  li  a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #000; 
    -webkit-transition:background 1s ease;
-moz-transition:background 1s ease;
-o-transition:background 1s ease;
transition:background 1s ease;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <button type="btn btn-navbar" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button> <a class="brand" href="#"><img class="pull-left "src="img/logo.png" /></a>

                <!--<a class="navbar-brand pull-left" href="#"><img class="pull-left "src="img/logo.png" /></a>-->
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right ">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bikes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Store</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Navbar example</h1>

        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        <p> <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="../../docs/#navbar">View navbar docs »</a>

        </p>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I left out that in the head i did add the bootstrap css as well so im assuming I have all the necessary components...

Comment: Please try re-stating your question. It sounds like you want a drop-down. A Collapsing nav in bootstrap changes form on a narrow window / mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are mixing Bootstrap 2 and Bootstrap 3 code.

Check this out:
[Live view](http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/FW9jC/show/#)
[Edit view](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/FW9jC/)

I've taken your exact HTML and CSS, but used Bootstrap 2 CSS and JS

If you do indeed want to use Bootstrap 3, double check you have the correct CSS and JS files, and you will see that the HTML for the navbar has changed, you can grab a sample navbar from

```
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar
```

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Good luck